# How to get context out of a (Single) sentence?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am fairly new to NLP,

I want to implement a python based clustering algorithm, it will be having :

- Context/Topic Extraction - From the Title Statement (Will probably contain not more than 6-7 words)
- Clustering Algorithm

So the problem is, that I have a bunch of statements(20 statements * 5-6 words per statement = 100-120 words) all related to a Title Statement. And an Algorithm should be able to cluster them.

For the (1) - As an input, first I will have a Title, from that title I want to extract various topics, for ex :

***TITLE : "Problem in Manufacturing Assembly Line"*** - From this I want to extract something like

*1. Mechanical Problems*

*2. Electrical Problems*

*3. Linemen Management*

*4. Supply Chain Management Problems*......

And use these extracted topics to cluster those statements. I can perform the second task of clustering, but how do I extract topics from a single statement that contains not more than 6-7 words?

Language : ***English***

Any idea how to go about the first problem??

Answer (score 1):

Well the short version is you need more data. You can make a topic model (I would recommend looking into LDA - problably guidedLDA), but you're definitely going to need more of..well everything. First, 6 different documents are nowhere near enough. Second, 6 words/document is also not enough. Is there any reasons you want to extract the topic from just the title instead of the full document - because at least the full doc will have more words?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Because based on the Topics Extracted from the Title, Tags shall be suggested to the end user for them to select. Selected tags will narrow down the classes among which the clustering need to be performed. But yes, alternative could be of using the entire text(TITLE+STATEMENTS) to figure out the classes. I have looked into the Dependency Parsers(https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) as well, something which doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: I would use the entire text, you don't really seem to provide a good reason to only use the titles. The text at least gives more context. But realistically, you're not going to get anywhere with only 6 documents. You need data. Still, look into guidedLDA.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at it.